# how to bind value of javascript to a lable in asp C#

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a Javascript rails slider with changeable value, i want to bind its value to a asp label and use in in code behind, thanks for your help.

lable:

```
<asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#appearance7").roundSlider({
        radius: 70,
        width: 8,
        handleSize: "+16",
        handleShape: "dot",
        sliderType: "min-range",
        value: 5,
        max: 10,
        mouseScrollAction: true,
        min: 1
        });
</script>
```

the current value is "5" but it can be changed by user and i want to assign this value to asp label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $("#appearance7").roundSlider({
        radius: 70,
        width: 8,
        handleSize: "+16",
        handleShape: "dot",
        sliderType: "min-range",
        value: 5,
        max: 10,
        mouseScrollAction: true,
        min: 1,
        change: "onValueChange"
        });
        
function onValueChange (e) {
    $("#Lbl1").val(e.value);
}
```

```html
<asp:Label ID="Lbl1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```